# Why am I getting a parse error in this PHP code?

Tags: php

Here is my error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/socia125/public_html/poke.php on line 19

This is line 19 of my code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO feed (user_id, feed_text, time) VALUES($user,'You'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kiss_option']).'yourself',UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO feed (user_id, feed_text, time)
        VALUES($user, 'You ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kiss_option'])." yourself', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
```

Comment: Just about to write that up :)

Comment: thanks for your fast responses..this worked i appreciate the help

Comment: What does it means "unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING" ?